# Invalid identifier error ORA-00904 when trying to use && substitution variable

Tags: sql, oracle

I used the following code to define a couple substitution variables

```
Select '&&my_name' "my name", '&&my_birthday' "date born" from dual;
```

I want to use the date_born variable in subsequent calls in the select statement but keep getting the ORA-00904 error. Below is the code I'm trying:

```
Select '&&my_name' "my name", '&&my_birthday' "date born", TO_DATE("date born") from dual;
```

or

```
Select '&&my_name' "my name", '&&my_birthday' "date born", TO_DATE(my_birthday) from dual;
```

Any ideas? I must be defining or calling the variable or column incorrectly.

Comment: [Reference a Calculated Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413764/sql-server-reference-a-calculated-column#413784) The simple answer is, you cannot use column defined at the same level. You need to use expression twice. `Select '&&my_name' "my name", '&&my_birthday' "date born", TO_DATE('&&my_birthday') from dual;`

Comment: How are the variables `my_name` and `my_birthday` defined in SQL*Plus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DUAL doesn't have a `"date born"` column.

Try this:

```
with demo (my_name, date_born) as
     ( select '&&my_name', '&&my_birthday' from dual )
select my_name, to_date(date_born)
from   demo;
```

or this

```
select my_name, to_date(date_born)
from   ( select '&&my_name' as my_name, '&&my_birthday' as date_born from dual );
```

I have used standard naming rather than double-quoting everything.

`to_date(date_born)` is a bit of a gamble on the date format and language happening to match your session defaults. I would prefer to specify a date format, for example by ensuring that `'&&my_birthday'` is formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD` and then

```
select '&&my_name' as my_name, date '&&my_birthday' as date_born from dual;
```

Edit: alternatively, as lad2025 pointed out, since you are using `&&` you can use the same variable multiple times in the same statement.